# Capturing a single frame with Python (using a webcam)

Tags: python, image, opencv, webcam

I checked other solutions, but they weren't answering my question. 
My issue is that whenever I try to capture just one frame from a video (I want to basically take a picture with my webcam) I just get a black window.

Code -

```
import cv2


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame = cam.read()[1]
cv2.imwrite('img2.png', frame)
cv2.imshow("img1", frame)
```

screenshot - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOLCD.jpg

My webcam is USB, 720p at 30fps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two things. It might be that you need to add a `waitKey()` after `cv2.imshow()`. Alternatively, you aren't checking the return from the camera for any errors. It could be a connection problem. Here are the two things to do.

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
retval, frame = cam.read()
if retval != True:
    raise ValueError("Can't read frame")

cv2.imwrite('img2.png', frame)
cv2.imshow("img1", frame)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The `waitKey()` function halts the program until a user has entered a key in the window.

Comment: it still didn't work...i even pressed a key and after that i restarted the computer but I still get the same black window as shown in the screenshot link..

Comment: @SajjadAbbas what's being returned by `retval`? What is coming up in `img2.png`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to see the retval return. However, img2 is literally just all black, like the screenshot.

Comment: @SajjadAbbas Why not just `retval, frame = cam.read(); print(retval)`?
If `img2.png` is black, it suggests it's a problem with your camera connection, not with `imshow`. Can you access the webcam using another method? Skype, Photobooth something like that?

Comment: retval shows true. The camera works with anything else, like skype and whatnot.

Comment: Alright it just started working - I tried a different program!

Comment: That could be a driver issue then. Sometimes other programs can do some weird driver config behind the scenes.