# How to read a single frame with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Whenever I try to capture just one frame from a video (I want to basically take a picture with my webcam) I just get a black window. I am having the same problems as SajjadAbbas in the comments in:

[Capturing a single frame with Python (using a webcam)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824785/capturing-a-single-frame-with-python-using-a-webcam)

My code is very simple and I suspect there may be a problem with the drivers but have no idea how to remedy that. He says he was able to get it to work by using a different program, but I cannot comment to find out what exactly he means by that.

```
`import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = cap.read()
print(ret)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

while(True):
    cv2.imshow('frame', rgb)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: Why are you converting to `BGRA` (i.e. adding a transparency layer)? Adding a transparency layer only serves to confuse `cv2.imshow()` and it is then discarded when written as a JPEG because JPEGs don't support transparency. Also why are you entering a loop at all if you just want one frame? Change to `waitKey(0)` and then exit the program - no need for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you want the webcam to run and when you press "q" it captures an image with the name "capture.jpg"?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        cv2.imwrite("capture.jpg", frame)
```